# Adding pictures to locations in Google IOS Maps SDK

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

How do I add pictures to a location where I have a marker in Google Maps IOS SDK?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have done my research.  I have construct an entire IOS App using Google Maps IOS SDK.  I know we can place markers on the maps, and drop overlays.  However, I don't see any info in the headers about adding a picture to a location based on user place marker.

Comment: Do you mean a ground overlay (ie the picture is displayed as an overlay on the map), or do you mean use a picture for the marker, or do you mean that when the marker is tapped, a picture is displayed?

Comment: From what I understand, GSMarkerOptions class allows you to set the title.  I wanted to set if there was a way to set a picture, just as you would set the title in GSMarkerOptions class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `icon` property of `GMSMarkerOptions` to a `UIImage`.

There is an example of this here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#customize_a_marker

**UPDATE:**

You can use a `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture. You would need to resize the returned `UIImage`, to make it small enough for a marker.

You can use the `myLocation` property on the `GMSMapView` to get the current location to add the marker to. You would need to set `myLocationEnabled` to `YES` on the `GMSMapView` when you first create the map view, in order for `myLocation` to track your current location.

Comment: What if I want the user in the map application to add a picture during runtime of application?  How would I do that?  I want to take a picture as a user, and then add it to Google Maps IOS SDK based on location.